# INSERT new row IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, insert

```
Table contents:
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | title   | author    |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 | book_1  | author_1  |
|  2 | book_2  | author_2  |
|  3 | book_3  | author_3  |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

`id` - is UNIQUE and AUTO_INCREMENTAL

How to prevent INSERT of duplicate row (duplicate only by `title` and `author` columns) to be executed?

For example, this should be ignored in case it's executed (because we already have `'book_2','author_2'`):

```
INSERT INTO books (id, title, author) VALUES (NULL,'book_2','author_2');
```

But these kind of INSERTs to be allowed (because we don't have yet `'book_4','author_4'`; `'book_2','author_4'`)

```
INSERT INTO books (id, title, author) VALUES (NULL,'book_4','author_4');
INSERT INTO books (id, title, author) VALUES (NULL,'book_2','author_4');
```

Comment: Create unique index on fields `title` and `author`

Comment: but this one should still be allowed: `INSERT INTO books (id, title, author) VALUES (NULL,'book_2','author_4');`

Comment: *but this one should still be allowed* Please try previousy - it's possible that you may not need to comment.

Comment: First comment by @Slava Rozhnev means a compound unique index on both columns..not 2 indexes and should be what you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create table with `UNIQUE KEY` like: ([fiddle1](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=834c604d370a42c38deceb42452774a6&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80))

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
  `title` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
  `author` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_book` (`title`, `author`), 
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

If table already exists you can alter it by adding `UNIQUE KEY`: ([fiddle2](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=918a30810d22bef556dc9941d9f044f0&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80))

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `unique_book` ON `books` (`title`, `author`);
```

Comment: and use INSERT IGNORE after that?

Comment: You can use `INSERT IGNORE` just be noticed  about it increment `id`

Comment: and this row would be added, right? `INSERT INTO books (id, title, author) VALUES (NULL,'book_2','author_4');`

Comment: Sure. Just try on SQLize.online: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=834c604d370a42c38deceb42452774a6&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80

Comment: thank you! how to avoid `id` going up on duplicates in this case?

Comment: You can create stored procedure that will check record existent before insert